# What should we write for the tag wiki excerpt for the tag [convert-to-answer]?

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

Yesterday, I suggested edits for both the tag wiki and tag wiki excerpt for the tag [convert-to-answer](/questions/tagged/convert-to-answer), and my tag wiki edit was approved, but my tag wiki excerpt was rejected.

You can see here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/88672

I took a reference from the tag wiki excerpt given for the tag [answers-as-comments](/questions/tagged/answers-as-comments), [comments-as-answers](/questions/tagged/comments-as-answers). I found that the tag wiki excerpt of the tag given is part of the same as the tag wiki given.

I already read the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/tag-excerpts) given from there, and the reason why my edit was rejected, but the problem now is we don’t have a tag wiki excerpt for the tag [convert-to-answer](/questions/tagged/convert-to-answer), have anyone got any ideas for the tag wiki excerpt?

I don’t have any ideas for providing basic guidance on when to use this tag.

Comment: I can't really explain, so I just edited it myself. Sorry for "stealing" potential 2 points! :)

Comment: @ShadowWizardLoveZelda So, what should I do with this question now?

Comment: FYI, your added extended tag wiki for the tag isn't accurate - there's no system feature to convert comments into answers, only the other way around. If you look at the posts using the tag, you'll see they're about hand-conversions.

Comment: @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog Sorry, then can you help me to change the description of the tag [tag:answers-as-comments], as the description is wrong too. (I’m lazy too suggested edit.)

Comment: Also, a fact for context: the existing excerpts for the two tags you mentioned were contributed in 2011, when the guidelines and intent were way less clear.

Comment: @user1176409 well everything can be always improved, so the question can stay, and one might suggest something better, or find a way to explain how to write it better. No harm is keeping the question around, as the tag wiki can always be edited.